# R3.4.1 Read data from multiple .csv files

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to build up a function that can import/read several data tables in .csv files, and then compute statistics on the selected files.
Each of the 332 .csv file contains a table with the same column names: Date, Pollutant and id. There are a lot of missing values.

This is the function I wrote so far, to compute the mean of values for a pollutant:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) { 

  library(dplyr)
  setwd(directory)
  good<-c()

  for (i in (id)){
    task1<-read.csv(sprintf("%03d.csv",i))
  }

  p<-select(task1, pollutant)
  good<-c(good,complete.cases(p))
  mean(p[good,]) 
}
```

The problem I have is that each time it goes through the loop a new file is read and the data already read are replaced by the data from the new file.
So I end up with a function working perfectly fine with 1 single file, but not when I want to select multiple files 
e.g. if I ask for id=10:20, I end up with the mean calculated only on file 20.

How could I change the code so that I can select multiple files?

Thank you!

Comment: You're re-defining `good` as `c()` at the start of every loop iteration. To get what you want, you should define `good` *outside* the loop. (And while we're at it, load your package / set your working directory outside the loop as well.)

Answer (score 1):

My answer offers a way of doing what you want to do (if I understood everything correctly) without using a loop. My two assumptions are: (1) you have 332 *.csv files with the same header (column names) - so all file are of the same structure, and (2) you can combine your tables into one big data frame.

If these two assumptions are correct, I would use a list of your files to import your files as data frames (so this answer does not contain a loop function!).

```
# This creates a list with the name of your file. You have to provide the path to this folder.
file_list <- list.files(path = [your path where your *.csv files are saved in], full.names = TRUE)

# This will create a list of data frames.
mylist <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)

# This will 'row-bind' the data frames of the list to one big list.
mydata <- rbindlist(mylist)

# Now you can perform your calculation on this big data frame, using your column information to filter or subset to get information of just a subset of this table (if necessary).
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! I had not think of using the rbind function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) { 
    od <- setwd(directory)
    on.exit(setwd(od))

    task_list <- lapply(sprintf("%03d.csv", id), read.csv)
    p_list <- lapply(task_list, function(x) complete.cases(select(x, pollutant)))
    mean(sapply(p_list, mean))
}
```

Notes:
 - Put all your `library` calls at the beginning of your scripts, they will be much easier to read. Never inside a function.
 - To set a working directory inside a function is also a bad idea. When the function returns, that change will still be on and you might get lost. The better way is to set wd's outside functions, but since you've set it inside the function, I've addapted the code accordingly.

Comment: thank you! it does not work exactly as such as it still computes several means of several tables, and not a global mean - but it's interesting to use the lapply function!

Comment: @CécilePetit OK, I will edit my code and have it compute a global mean.

Comment: Thank you!In the meantime I changed my code as follows: